# cakePHP - Model, Controller without convention/ member returns null

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a Problem with cakePHP.

This is my Model:

```
<?php
class Veranstaltung extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Veranstaltung';
    var $useTable = 'veranstaltungen';
}
?>
```

and this is my Controller:

```
<?php
class VeranstaltungenController extends AppController
{
    var $name = 'Veranstaltungen';
    public function index()
    {
        $this->set('veranstaltungen',$this->Veranstaltung->find('all'));
    }

}
?>
```

but `$this->Veranstaltung` Returns null.

How do I solve this?

Comment: You don't need var $name = 'Veranstaltungen'; in your controller. Also did you configure your database poperly?

Comment: yes, the database is correct.

Comment: Please don't progamm in your local language, use english instead! Not only because that's how it's done pretty much all around the world, but in this specific case it's also crucial since the Inflector that CakePHP uses for figuring names based on conventions, is for english words only!

Comment: I already did earlier, but my employer want's to have it in our language :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to include your model in controller. Do do this add `$uses` field in your controller which is type of `array`:

```
class VeranstaltungenController extends AppController
{
     public $uses = array('Veranstaltung');

     public function index()
     {
         $this->set('veranstaltungen',$this->Veranstaltung->find('all'));
     }
}
```

[Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::$uses)

If there still be a problem it could be required to use

```
App::uses('Veranstaltung', 'Model');
```

before your controller class definition.

---

And please forget about `var` keyboard, because it's only for backward compatibility with PHP4.

> In order to maintain backward compatibility with PHP 4, PHP 5 will
>   still accept the use of the keyword `var` in property declarations
>   instead of (or in addition to) `public`, `protected`, or `private`. However,
>   var is no longer required. In versions of PHP from 5.0 to 5.1.3, the
>   use of `var` was considered deprecated and would issue an `E_STRICT`
>   warning, but since PHP 5.1.3 it is no longer deprecated and does not
>   issue the warning.

Comment: As you can see the name of model is "Veranstaltung" $use in controller should load this model automatically.

Comment: @Fury but with convention controller should have name `VeranstaltungsController` instead of `VeranstaltungenController`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes. I didn't see the plural "s"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `var $name = 'Veranstaltungen';` in your controller.

Also make sure you have configured your database properly?

Then try this:

```
$this->loadModel("Veranstaltungen");
$this->set('veranstaltungen',$this->Veranstaltung->find('all'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
    class VeranstaltungenController extends AppController

    var $uses = array('Veranstaltungen');
    public function index()
    {
        $this->set('veranstaltungen',$this->Veranstaltung->find('all'));
    }
   } 
 ?>
```

Try in your controller

Comment: This var $uses = 'Veranstaltungen';  is not right. If he wants to add more model to $use then what?